# declare all property in object the same type in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know I can declare type for object like so in typescript:

```
interface PersonType {
    fname: string
    lname: string
}
const person: PersonType = {fname:"John", lname:"Doe"};
```

but is there a way to declare all the property have the string type? I don't want to specify any property key and type.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: `interface IPersonType { [key: string]: string; }`

Comment: still you need to create an interface

Comment: Object can have **any** keys?

Answer (score 1):

If you still need to use only interface, you can do next:

```js
interface PersonType {
    [index: string]: string
}

const person: PersonType = {fname:"John", lname:"Doe"};
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) you can find the docs

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Record<Keys,Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)> utility:

> Constructs a type with a set of properties `Keys` of type `Type`

```
const foo: Record<string, string> = { fname: "John", lname: "Doe" };
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAuGAlApqATgEwDzRYCWYA5gDQyEmkB8MAvDAN7xgCGAtuigEQBSIABZhelADYdufACIh0vGAF8A3EA)

---

`Record` is an alias for:

```
type Record<K extends string | number | symbol, T> = { [P in K]: T; }
```